# Lightswitch app publishing to Azure is failing on service configuration line

Tags: azure, lightswitch-2012

In publishing a Lightswitch app to Azure (for the first time) I get to the Service Configuration line and the "Select a web site to host your application". I have created the website on Azure as well as a SQL database and linked them.  I have download the Pay-As-You-Go-Free Trial-5-10-2014-credentials.publishsettings file and imported it numerous times, hit the refresh button--everything.  The Security Settings and Data Connections are all ok. My only guess is that there is a corrupt file that needs to be deleted but I really cannot guess anymore about what has gone wrong.
The only thing that comes up in the "Select a web site to host your application: dropdown is ".  Prehaps I missing some setup step on the Azure portal. I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Found the work around on these links in the Microsoft forums.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4f31d311-dfc2-47ac-80e1-64af0487717e/cant-publish-vs2013-ls-project-this-subscription-has-no-web-sites?forum=lightswitch

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david_kidder/archive/2013/07/19/publish-lightswitch-2013-preview-applications-to-windows-azure-web-sites-without-the-azure-sdk.aspx